# grunt-filerev/grunt-usemin doesn't update reference to svg file

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I use the following JS snippet from http://iconmelon.com/#/how-to-use to include their icons right before the cloding body tag

```
<script>
    var url ='images/icons.svg';
    var c=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    c.open('GET', url, false); 
    c.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml'); c.send();
    document.body.insertBefore(c.responseXML.firstChild, 
                               document.body.firstChild)
</script>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work with grunt-filerev/grunt-usemin because it renames the svg-file but it doesn't update the reference in the line

```
var url ='images/icons.svg';
```

How could I fix this? Is there a way to force grunt-usemin to update the reference at this position?